# A simpler way to write the calculator class in OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have created a class called Calculator with the add, subtract, multiply and divide function. The calculator is limited to adding two numbers and returning the result.
I am relatively new to OOP,would like to get some input on the class, did i take the long route and if i did is there another way to simplify the class.

Here is the code:

```
class Calculator {
    private $_val1 , $_val2;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2){
        $this->_val1 = $val1;
        $this->_val2 = $val2;
    }

    public function add(){
        return $this->_val1 + $this->_val2;
    }

    public function subtract(){
        return $this->_val1 - $this->_val2;
    }

    public function multiply (){
        return $this->_val1 * $this->_val2;
    }

    public function divide () {
        return $this->_val1 / $this->_val2;
    }
}

$calc = new Calculator(3,4);
echo "<p>3 + 4 = ".$calc->add(). "</p>";

$calc = new Calculator (15,12);
echo "<p>15 - 12 = ".$calc->subtract(). "</p>";

$calc = new Calculator (20,2);
echo "<p> 20 * 2 = ".$calc->multiply(). "</p>";

$calc = new Calculator (20,2);
echo "<p> 20 / 2 = ".$calc ->divide(). "</p>";
```

Comment: Please take a minute to align the code properly. It is barely possible to read the code when it is all messed up.

Comment: Aligned it for you. :-)

Comment: ah sorry, I guess we edited in parallel :)

Answer (score 8):

IMHO, you should use Polymorphism.
[This Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc) may help you understanding this principle

Here's my way of thinking.

First, define an interface for any operations you'd need

```
interface OperationInterface
{
    public function evaluate(array $operands = array());
}
```

Then, create the calculator holder

```
class Calculator
{
    protected $operands = array();

    public function setOperands(array $operands = array())
    {
        $this->operands = $operands;
    }

    public function addOperand($operand)
    {
        $this->operands[] = $operand;
    }

    /**
     * You need any operation that implement the given interface
     */
    public function setOperation(OperationInterface $operation)
    {
        $this->operation = $operation;
    }

    public function process()
    {
        return $this->operation->evaluate($this->operands);
    }
}
```

Then you can define an operation, for example, addition

```
class Addition implements OperationInterface
{
    public function evaluate(array $operands = array())
    {
        return array_sum($operands);
    }
}
```

And you would use it like :

```
$calculator = new Calculator;
$calculator->setOperands(array(4,2));
$calculator->setOperation(new Addition);

echo $calculator->process(); // 6
```

With that point, if you want to add any new behaviour, or modify an existing one, just create or edit a class.

For example, say you want a Modulus operation

```
class Modulus implements OperationInterface
{
    public function evaluate(array $operands = array())
    {
        $equals = array_shift($operands);

        foreach ($operands as $value) {
            $equals = $equals % $value;
        }

        return $equals;
    }
}
```

Then,

```
$calculator = new Calculator;
$calculator->setOperands(array(4,2));
$calculator->setOperation(new Addition); // 4 + 2

echo $calculator->process(); // 6

$calculator->setOperation(new Modulus); // 4 % 2

echo $calculator->process(); // 0

$calculator->setOperands(array(55, 10)); // 55 % 10

echo $calculator->process(); // 5
```

---

#### This solution allows your code to be a third-party library

If you plan to reuse this code or give it away as a library, the user wouldn't by any case *modify your source code*.
But what if he wants a `Substraction` or a `BackwardSubstraction` method which are not defined ?

He just has to create his very own `Substraction` class in his project, which implements `OperationInterface` in order to work with your library.

#### It's easier to read

When looking in the project architecture it's easier to see a folder like this

```
- app/
    - lib/
        - Calculator/
            - Operation/
                - Addition.php
                - Modulus.php
                - Substraction.php
            - OperationInterface.php
            - Calculator.php
```

And immediatly know which file contains the desired behaviour.

Comment: might as well put some chaining capabilities to make `echo $calculator->setOperands(array(4,2))->setOperation(new Addition)->process();` possible?

Comment: Simply add `return $this;` on `setOperands` and `setOperation` methods

Comment: I love stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a plain calculator is a good example for OOP.  An object needs both a set of methods and a set of variables that represent its state, and can be used to differentiate instances of the object.  I would suggest trying to make "moody" calculators.  A calculator with a happy mood will add 2 to each result, and an angry calculator will subtract 2 from each result.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this

```
interface Evaluable {
    public function evaluate();
}

class Value implements Evaluable {
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function evaluate() {
        return $this->value();
    }
}

class Node implements Evaluable {
    protected $left;
    protected $right;

    public function __construct(Evaluable $left, Evaluable $right) {
        $this->left = $left;
        $this->right = $right;
    }
}

class SumNode extends Node {
    public function evaluate() {
        return $this->left->evaluate() + $this->right->evaluate();
    }
}

$op = new SumNode(new Value(2), new Value(3));
$result = $op->evaluate();
```

This way you can easyly add new operations

```
class SubNode extends Node {
    public function evaluate() {
        return $this->left->evaluate() - $this->right->evaluate();
    }
}
```

And chain operations like this

```
$sum1 = new SumNode(new Value(5), new Value(3));
$sum2 = new SumNode(new Value(1), new Value(2));
$op = new SubNode($sum1, $sum2);
$result = $op->evaluate();
```

Comment: My answer is similar to Touki's one. We both saw Misko's great video :p

Comment: Did you actually check the script? You have two missing things on first glance: `Class Node` does not implement the `evaluate()` method, and `Class Value` does not have a method `value()`, just a property `value`. But besides this it`s good to get the pattern idea! (Y)

Comment: Oops, I just figured, that on PHP >=5.4 you can have the "interfaced" methods implemented in a class extension...

Answer (score 1):

In general, we don't fix value in those kind of class.
Your methods should take their 2 values by arguments instead of picking private members.

Like the following:

```
public function add($v1, $v2)
{
    return $v1 + $v2;
}
```

Thus, Calculator becomes a tool, and we should not need to allocate this kind of object.
That's why Calculators methods should be **static**.

```
public static function add($v1, $v2)
{
    return $v1 + $v2;
}
```

In this way, all you need to call is `Calculator::add(1, 2)`.
You can find those kinds of class everywhere. Like Vector, Matrice in math or 3D. Or write to the output or anything like that.

Remember, it is a way to do that, neither the best nor the worst.

Comment: [Using static methods reduces testability](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html). They might be a good idea for simple utility functions that calculate a formula (like in this case) but if you want your classes to be unit-testable, please don't overuse static methods.

Comment: You might enjoy reading [Are Static Methods/Variables bad practice?](http://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice.html) - this dude's answer is a definite "Yes". I'd agree.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably end up doing something like

```
$calc = new Calculator();
$calc->sum($x, $y, $z);
$calc->substract($x, $y);
....
```

Take a look at this example. You can give any number of arguments like this using func_num_args()

```
<?php
function foo()
{
$numargs = func_num_args();
echo "Number of arguments: $numargs\n";
}

foo(1, 2, 3);   
?>
// output: Number of arguments: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This task has a lot of solutions, here is one of them:

```
 <?

class Calculator
{

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $_val1,
        $_val2;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private static $_result = 0;

    /**
     * @param $val1
     * @param $val2
     */
    public function __construct($val1 = '', $val2 = '')
    {
        if ((!empty($val1) && !empty($val2)) && (!is_numeric($val1) && !is_numeric($val2))) {
            $this->_val1 = (float)$val1;
            $this->_val2 = (float)$val2;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $val1
     */
    public function setVal1($val1)
    {
        $this->_val1 = (float)$val1;
    }

    /**
     * @param $val2
     */
    public function setVal2($val2)
    {
        $this->_val2 = (float)$val2;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $operator
     *
     * @return float|int|string
     */
    public function getResult($operator = '')
    {
        if (is_numeric($this->_val1) && is_numeric($this->_val2)) {
            switch ($operator) {
                case '+':
                    self::$_result = $this->_val1 + $this->_val2;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    self::$_result = $this->_val1 - $this->_val2;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    self::$_result = $this->_val1 * $this->_val2;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    self::$_result = $this->_val1 / $this->_val2;
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Alert alert alert)) some of operands not set or not number';
        }
        return self::$_result;
    }
}
```

And here is nice solution https://gist.github.com/cangelis/1442951

Comment: I'd definitely add a default case (with an exception) to the switch to protect against typos and unknown operands. Also, you should throw an exception instead of doing an echo. Without exceptions, the code will return undefined results, leading to PHP error messages and/or weird behavior. Apart from that, see my other comment for the suggestion of chandresh_cool.